How to get new react native architecture in my Expo native?
New new react native architecture is out but I work with Expo native. If I create a new expo native project will it run the new react native architecture ?

from expo site :
The SDK 52 beta period begins today and will last approximately two weeks. The beta is an opportunity for developers to test out the SDK and ensure that the new release does not introduce any regressions for their particular systems and app configurations. We will be continuously releasing fixes and improvements during the beta period, some of these may include breaking changes.
SDK 52 beta includes React Native 0.76.0. The full release notes for SDK 52 won't be available until the stable release, but you can browse the changelogs in the expo/expo repo to learn more about the scope of the release and any breaking changes. We'll merge all changelogs into the root CHANGELOG.md when the beta is complete.
https://expo.dev/changelog/2024/10-24-sdk-52-beta
